# How to set Custom DNS for Android or Flutter app

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-ndk

I want to add custom IPV4 dns like 1.1.1.1 in my android or flutter app
it means that all of the traffic of my application such as firebase/glide/retrofit have to route from my custom dns

how should i implement this ?

i'd already tried some ways in NDK to set DNS for whole android device
but i dont want to touch android DNS , just my application should use that dns

Answer (score 1):

### What are you trying to achieve?

This looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You are probably trying to achieve something we don't know with your custom DNS (like replacing a request to a certain host with a different server), but we don't know for sure because you think changing the DNS server to your app will be a better solution for whatever problem you have, but the fact is that it is very hard.

### While technically feasible, it is extremely challenging.

It is not possible to change the DNS just for one application, as the DNS configuration is global to the device, so any network request will use the DNS servers of the device by default.

The only possible way of implementing this would be reinventing the wheel: using [DnsResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/DnsResolver) to manually query the DNS server for each of the target hosts, and then making requests to the specific IP addresses.

But with HTTP you will find out that if you make a request to an IP address, that IP address will be the origin header instead of the domain name, and the only solution to that would be using bare sockets and implementing all the HTTP payloads and headers manually to give a different origin.

It won't work with Firebase and other closed source SDKs as well, since you cannot modify them. It would only work for requests sent by your own code, or SDKs allowing you to change the server address.

Comment: The issue is that using the default DNS resolution server might have some issues, and I suspect there might be problems with the Dart `dart:io` DNS resolution logic. This suspicion may be causing some officially unresolved bugs related to slow requests. Therefore, I want to modify the DNS resolution server to specify a more stable one.